# CKEditor 4 : Javascript is disappearing when switching between source and regular view

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

When I paste a javascript code inside the source and switch to regular view and come back to source the javascript is disappearing.
My need is to make a small bit of script editable to users.
https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/htmlformatting.html

Comment: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/examples/acf.html

Comment: config.allowedContent = true;
Solved my issue. Thanks @Wizard